# AutoDockTools crash at launch

Tags: python, crash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bioinformatics

This is my first post so I hope I respect the posting format.
I installed [mgltools](https://ccsb.scripps.edu/mgltools/) recently to do some docking and I don't know why but when running  adt (AutoDockTools) or pmv (Python Molecular Viewer), which are part of mgltools, the software crashes. I get the following error without additionnal information:

I'm running on WSL2 with Ubuntu.
Sometimes I get this:

```
mabagar@ApeX:~$ which adt
/home/mabagar/MGLTools-1.5.7/bin/adt
mabagar@ApeX:~$ adt
Run ADT from  /home/mabagar/MGLTools-1.5.7/MGLToolsPckgs/AutoDockTools
MSMSLIB 1.4.4 started on ApeX
Copyright M.F. Sanner (March 2000)
Compilation flags
Segmentation fault
mabagar@ApeX:~$
```

and sometimes this:

```
mabagar@ApeX:~$ adt
Run ADT from  /home/mabagar/MGLTools-1.5.7/MGLToolsPckgs/AutoDockTools
MSMSLIB 1.4.4 started on ApeX
Copyright M.F. Sanner (March 2000)
Compilation flags
malloc(): unaligned tcache chunk detected
Aborted
mabagar@ApeX:~$
```

The GUI always crashes around 30-40%. I am suspecting a failure with my  graphical system or with my memory but I don't know how to investigate it. I am using the VcXserv to use  Linux windows for my wsl2.
I really don't know what to look at to fix it so I am asking for your help. Thanks for reading this !

I tried installing and uninstalling mgltools several times, both 1.5.6 and 1.5.7 versions  with and without the GUI installer. I also installed mgltools on the Windows system and it works perfectly but I want it to work in wsl2. I looked at the binary file and the python scripts that run the software but I don't have core knowledge of linux which I started using this year for my master's degree.